# AXAcroPDF will not load

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I have a `PDF` `COM` control on a `Windows Forms Application`. The process is simple, a file path is sent to a `Sub`, it checks if the file exists and if so, loads the file on my `PDF` control and shows the form. The code is simple:

```
Public Sub LoadPDF(ByVal pathPDF As String)
    MessageBox.Show(pathPDF)
    If System.IO.File.Exists(pathPDF) Then
        frmPDF.dePDF.LoadFile(pathPDF)
        frmPDF.Show()

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No image available. Please check FEMA and CAMSIS.")
        frmPDF.Hide()
    End If
End Sub
```

This code worked 2 hours ago. The same code still works in other applications (that pull the exact same file path). I have compared designer codes/control properties/etc between the current application and the others. I can't find a difference at all.  I have tried completely recreating the form and COM control.

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

**My solution:**

The reference .dll files were corrupt. I used the solution here [C# System.AccessViolationException and System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20407868/c-sharp-system-accessviolationexception-and-system-runtime-interopservices-sehex)
to fix it. Everything seems to be running fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
axAcroPDF1.src = PDFPath;
```

To load your PDF into the control instead of LoadFile.

Comment: I should have added that I've tried setting the pdf src property as well with no luck.

Comment: When you use LoadFile, does it return true? Try using it in a conditional statement, so `AxAcroPDF.LoadFile(Path) = True` The function itself is a bool so you'll be able to test directly if the path you gave it is even responding how you think.

Comment: Timmy, the boolean returns True. Great suggestion though, I didn't know that function could return true/false.

Comment: Hm, that's the strangest thing. I'm not expert on that Controller or anything close! I've only used it once or twice.  I wish I could help more past this point, but I'm limited on this.  If it boils down to it, Adobe has some pretty good reference manuals out there for this controller that might contain the answer. Let me know if you dig up an answer, I'd be happy to learn why also.                                                                      -Best of luck!